# Python ctypes writing data to be read by C executable

Tags: python, c, pointers, ctypes

I'm trying to learn how to use the Python ctypes library to write data to a file that can easily be read by C executables. In the little test case that I've put together, I'm running into some problems with reading/writing character arrays.

At the moment, I have three source files. `write_struct.py` creates a simple struct with two
entries, an integer value called `git` and a character array called `command`, then writes the struct to a file using `ctypes.fwrite`. `read_struct.c` and `read_struct.h` compile into an executable that internally defines an identical struct to the one in `write_struct.py`, then reads in the data written by the python script and prints it out.

At the moment, the following values are assigned in the python file (not literally in the manner shown below, scroll down to see the actual code):

```
git = 1
command = 'cp file1 file2'
```

And when run, the C executable prints the following:

```
git: 1
command:
```

I realize that the problem is almost certainly in how the `command` variable is being assigned in the python script. I have read that `c_char_p()` (the function I'm currently using to initialize the data in that variable) does not create a pointer to mutable memory, and `create_string_buffer()` should be used instead, however I'm not sure about how this works with either adding that data to a struct, or writing it to a file. I guess I'm also confused about how writing pointers/their data to a file works in the first place. What is the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks in advance to anyone that is able to help!!

The code of my three files is below for reference:

`write_struct.py`:

```
"""
write_struct.py
"""

from ctypes import *

libc = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")

class DataStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("git", c_int),
                ("command", c_char_p)
                ]

def main():
    pydata = DataStruct(1, c_char_p("cp file1 file2"))

    libc.fopen.argtypes = c_char_p, c_char_p
    libc.fopen.restype = c_void_p

    libc.fwrite = libc.fwrite
    libc.fwrite.argtypes = c_void_p, c_size_t, c_size_t, c_void_p
    libc.fwrite.restype = c_size_t

    libc.fclose = libc.fclose
    libc.fclose.argtypes = c_void_p,
    libc.fclose.restype = c_int


    f = libc.fopen("stored_data", "wb")
    libc.fwrite(byref(pydata), sizeof(pydata), 1, f)
    libc.fclose(f)
    return 0

main()
```

`read_struct.c`:

```
/*
 * read_struct.c
 *
 */

#include "read_struct.h"

int main()
{
  data_struct cdata = malloc(DATASIZE);
  FILE *fp;
  if ((fp = fopen("stored_data", "r")) != NULL) {
    fread(cdata, DATASIZE, 1, fp);
    printf("git: %i\n", cdata->git);
    printf("command:");
    printf("%s\n", cdata->command);
    fclose(fp);
  } else {
    printf("Could not open file\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

`read_struct.h`:

```
/*
 * read_struct.h
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _data_struct *data_struct;
struct _data_struct {
  int git;
  char command[40];
};
#define DATASIZE sizeof(struct _data_struct)
```

Comment: The logical question arises: why using *CTypes*? Why not simply write from *Python*? Also: you're writing the **memory address, not the contents that it points to**. Also the 2 structures don't match. It should be `("command", c_char * 40)`.

Comment: ah yeah, I knew they didn't match but to be honest I wasn't sure the correct ctypes data type to use for a multi-character array. I didn't realize it was just `c_char * 40`, so thank you!! and can you clarify exactly what you mean by writing just straight from python instead of using ctypes? The important thing for me is that the file doesn't have to be parsed at all when it is read by the c executable, I would love to be able to just read it straight into memory. Is there an alternative way to do this that might be logistically better?

Comment: Take a look at scipy.weave (A module to write C code in Python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write binary data directly with Python. `ctypes` can be used to create the structure and supports bit fields and unions, or for simple structures the `struct` module can be used.

```
from ctypes import *

class DataStruct(Structure):
    _fields_ = [("git", c_int),
                ("command", c_char * 40)] # You want array here, not pointer

pydata = DataStruct(1,b'cp file1 file2')  # byte string for initialization.
with open('stored_data','wb') as f:       # write file in binary mode
    f.write(pydata)                       # ctypes support conversion to bytes
```

```
import struct

# See struct docs for formatting codes
# i = int (native-endian.  Use <i to force little-endian, >i for big-endian)
# 40s = char[40] (zero-padded if initializer is shorter)
pydata = struct.pack('i40s',1,b'cp file1 file2')
with open('stored_data2','wb') as f:
    f.write(pydata)
```

Ref: https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#format-strings